# Regular expression to match multiple cases

Tags: regex

How do we match the **white space (\s+)** in the following string

```
input: 
       string [element] [element] ...
example:
          |   |               |  |               |  |  
       test   wow       "I have  space"    I\ also\ have
          |   |<-match this   |  |<-but not this |  |<-and not this
```

[element] can contain white spaces inside, but it will only be in one of the following two cases:

1. element is surrounded by "

   example: "I have many space   "
2. the white space is escaped

   example: I\ have\ white\ spaces\ \

A simple description of my question from **thg435**:

Match a whitespace, except when it's in quotes or escaped?

Comment: I think your question is confusing.

Comment: lol~ It's a very simple regular expression but with two cases that we need to exclude from the matched.

Comment: so you want to match a whitespace, except when it's in quotes or escaped?

Comment: @user3241843: It can't be very simple for you, otherwise you wouldn't ask, right? As for my confusion: Your wrote "but it will only be in one of the following two cases:" and your first case was "element is surrounded by "", whereas your example showed that this was exactly what you didn't want, i.e. it's confusing. Btw, are you sure you really need regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to find not escaped spaces
is to use the 'negative lookbehind assertion'.

```
(?<![\])\s
```

To find spaces that are not inside quotes is a little bit tricky.
The best way is to find text that is not inside quotes and extract spaces from it.

To extract quoted text you can use this expression:

```
"[^"]*"
```

If you want to make it combined,
I would recommend to do it this way:

1. Split the string to its quoted and unquoted parts.
2. Check Unquoted parts with the first re (with the assertion).
3. Extract spaces from the quoted part.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I chain them together into one expression?

Comment: great answer, thanks.  So can we say there's no logic operator like 'or' in regular expression?

Comment: With lookbehind/lookahead assertions you can try to get what you want, but the regular expression will be look really awful. There is  OR operator in regular expressions (`|`) but it is uselus in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
(?<!\\) (?=[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)
```

Example in python:

```
import re

test = r'abc def "quoted string" and "another one" and escaped \ space'
rx = r'(?<!\\) (?=[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)'
print test
print re.sub(rx, '_', test)
```

Result:

```
abc def "quoted string" and "another one" and escaped \ space
abc_def_"quoted string"_and_"another one"_and_escaped_\ space
```